# Deleting cell giving error and crashing app

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, custom-cell

I need some help figuring out why I am getting this error. I currently have a view controller (let's call it ADDPersonVC) appending a struct. The struct looks like the following:

```
import UIKit

struct Person {
    var Name: String?
    var PostNumber: String?
    var StoryNumber: String?
    var Compensation: String?
    var ProfileImageUrl: String?
}
```

I have a button in ADDPersonVC that appends labels in a second view controller's (let's call it considerationsTestVC) tableViewCell. The number of rows is determined by:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return ConsiderationsTestViewController.people.count
}
```

The addPersonButton code that appends the struc looks like:

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    ConsiderationsTestViewController.people.append(Person(Name: "\(nameTextField.text!)", PostNumber: "\(gridTextField.text!)", StoryNumber: "\(storyTextField.text!)", Compensation: "\(compensationTextField.text!)", ProfileImageUrl: "\(userProfileImageUrlLabel.text!)"))
    
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
            }
}
```

In ConsiderationsTestViewController I have a static var called people that looks like:

```
static var people: [Person] = []
```

I then am able to append the labels in the ConsiderationsTestViewContoller with the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AddPersonCell, for: indexPath) as! ConsiderationsCell
    
    let numberOfPeopleCells = ConsiderationsTestViewController.people[indexPath.row]
    
    
    cell.nameLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.Name
    cell.feedLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.PostNumber
    cell.storyLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.StoryNumber
    cell.compensationLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.Compensation
    cell.userImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: numberOfPeopleCells.ProfileImageUrl!)
    
    cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    
    cell.nameLabelC.numberOfLines = 0
    
    return cell
}
```

When I go to delete the cell I am using the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        
        ConsiderationsTestViewController.people.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
    }
}
```

When I slide on the cell and click delete I am getting the error:

```
 "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"
```

at the line:

```
ConsiderationsTestViewController.people.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

I've been researching this all week and would love some help with trying to solve this problem. I am happy that I am able to get the struct to act as an array and display the proper information correctly. I am also having a problem uploading it to Firebase - realtimeDatabase but that is a question for after I figure this out.

I appreciate all the help.

EDIT:

When I run a breakpoint on the delete function and get values it returns:

```
3 elements
 ▿ 0 : Person
 ▿ Name : Optional<String>
  - some : "Person's Name1"
 ▿ PostNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ StoryNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ Compensation : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ ProfileImageUrl : Optional<String>
  - some : "PROFILEIMAGE URL HERE"
 ▿ userID : Optional<String>
  - some : "B2Z4DlZ8RucvEQhz2NSUkquqc5P2"

 ▿ 1 : Person
 ▿ Name : Optional<String>
  - some : "Person's Name2"
 ▿ PostNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ StoryNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "11"
 ▿ Compensation : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ ProfileImageUrl : Optional<String>
  - some : "PROFILEIMAGE URL HERE"
 ▿ userID : Optional<String>
  - some : "Lbn9HL1WIpZTMFzpGWAXy7Ra0EA2"

 ▿ 2 : Person
 ▿ Name : Optional<String>
  - some : "Person's Name3"
 ▿ PostNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ StoryNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ Compensation : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ ProfileImageUrl : Optional<String>
  - some : "PROFILEIMAGE URL HERE"
 ▿ userID : Optional<String>
  - some : "NE6WVUfF6WQjJT9eeVSJgfvrrZW2"
```

I also tried this:

```
 po ConsiderationsTestViewController.people[indexPath.row]
```

I received the following:

```
 Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.13/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
  2020-08-06 11:14:34.945249-0700 BWM[10260:384634] Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.13/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
```

Comment: Have you set the breakpoint before removing?
Do you reload tableView on .people change?
You can check your static array on every step to ensure it behaves the way you expect

Comment: I set the breakpoint and all it shows is the entire array. I don't know how to append the array/remove the specific person at indexPath.row. I could really use some help.

Comment: The compiler says that index is out of range, did you check the index? 
This can happen when you did update your datasource (which is .people array) and forgot to reload tableView. Do you call tableView.reloadData on array change?

Comment: I am reloading the table when the addPersonButton is tapped in the AddPersonVC by using the following code:  DispatchQueue.main.async {
           NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
                }
    }

Comment: did you check the index? how much is it greater than the last index in the array?

Comment: How do I check it? I print the array every time I add a person.

Comment: You put a breakpoint right at the failing line, reach the bp and then print in lldb console `po ConsiderationsTestViewController.people` and `po indexPath.row` or just get the value from debug window (https://raygun.com/blog/debug-ios/)

Comment: Thank you for that trick! I just edited my question to show what I am currently getting in the console at the breakpoint.

Comment: @TiranUt I just added something that I believe will shed some more light but I am unaware of what it means.

Comment: You forgot to update your tableView after updating your data source. Add `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`

Comment: @Don Thank you so much! You're the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following code in my delete function"

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```